# iOS15 UICollectionView customs layout, after insert a item, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind always recreate a new header

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, ios15

```
// viewdidload register
[self.collectionView registerClass:[TestHeaderCollectionReusableView class]
            forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                   withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(NEHeaderCollectionReusableView.class)];

// viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind called
TestHeaderCollectionReusableView *view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                                                                  withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(TestHeaderCollectionReusableView.class)
                                                                                         forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLjpX.jpg)

on iOS15, after I insert an item

```
- (void)insertItem {
    [self.dataSourece.firstObject insertObject:@{
        @"title" : @"ins1"
    } atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath * path= [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[path]];
}
```

it will always recreate TestHeaderCollectionReusableView at the first time after I insert an item. but on iOS14, it will duque from cache.

don't know why.

Answer (score 6):

### FIXED UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader crash in iOS 15

In my collectionView I am only using headers. It works for iOS 14 but in iOS 15 crashes.

[App crashed on AppDelegate and i recieve this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmfvS.png)

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from
> -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: does not match the element kind it is being used for. When asked for a view
> of element kind 'UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader' the data source
> dequeued a view registered for the element kind
> 'MyCollectionReusableView'.'

**Register header**

```
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionReusableView")
```

**Then in UICollectionViewDataSource method**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionReusableView
        headerView.backgroundColor = .red
        // Configure header view .....
        return headerView
    }
```

**Replace forSupplementaryViewOfKind: and ofKind: from "MyCollectionReusableView" to UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader**

This is working for me.